# Leading zeroes, wierd behaviour

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

So the original problem is related to Linq-to-SQL but I really think its boils down to how Linq is handeling leading zeroes in strings. In my original solution I'm trying to replicate SQL's BETWEEN-clause with Linq and Entity Framework(*****) when I came across this odd leading zeroes behaviour, check out the example here:

myObj class

```
public class myObj
{
   public string A, B, C;
   public string Name;
   public myObj(string name, string a, string b, string c)
   {
      Name = name;
      A = a;
      B = b;
      C = c;
   }
}
```

Make a list consisting of three myObjs

```
List<myObj> myList = new List<myObj>();
```

Initiate them and give them names and values. Then add them to the list.

```
myObj moA = new myObj("noLeadingZero", "1000", "2000", "3000");
myObj moB = new myObj("noLeadingZero", "3000", "4000", "5000");
```

On the object "LeadingZero" I'll give the last value a leading zero.

```
myObj moC = new myObj("LeadingZero", "5500", "6000", "0300");
```

Then add them the list:

```
myList.Add(moA);
myList.Add(moB);
myList.Add(moC);
```

---

Now!

When trying with Linq to get all objects in the interval "-1" to "9999" I only end up with two out of my three objects. That can't be right! The "LeadingZero"-object should be in the result, because "0300" is above -1 and below 9999.

```
var match = (from lst in myList where
             lst.A.CompareTo("-1") >= 0 &&
             lst.A.CompareTo("9999") <= 0 &&

             lst.B.CompareTo("-1") >= 0 &&
             lst.B.CompareTo("9999") <= 0 &&

             lst.C.CompareTo("-1") >= 0 &&
             lst.C.CompareTo("9999") <= 0
             select lst).ToList();
```

If I remove the last part (*lst.C.CompareTo("-1") >= 0 && lst.C.CompareTo("9999") <= 0* ) or if I change the "-1" to "0" I'll get all three objects. But why does Linq behave like this?

---

*(*) In my original solution the "-1" value is saved instead of null.*

Comment: You are comparing *strings* not *numbers*. So you are comparing alphabetically.

Comment: It's not a weird behavior of Linq but the result of what the string comparison inside your query returns.

Comment: @HansKesting Indeed I know im comparing strings and not numbers. But shouldn't the comparison still yield "0300"?

I mean, in the original solution (with SQL+EF) the values is always saved as strings and some values can contain a leading zero (the original solution is for accountings).

Comment: @Will_Bachman: What's the result of comparing "Hello" to "Hella"? "123456789" to "123456788"? "123" to "onetwothree"?  Expressing the difference in strings numerically is very hard to understand. Your expectation of getting "0300" relies on you _coincidentally_ using strings that have numerical characters. But to a computer, "123" "apl" and "456" are all equally different from one another. It doesn't see the pattern that you do, because the pattern could be pure coincidence.

Comment: There is no interval "-1" to "9999" unless you are expecting "-1" to be between "1" and "112". Default string comparison in C# is to ignore hyphens because it is intended for use for alphabetizing words, not comparing numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Do a comparison of integers or declare A, B and C as int

```
var match = (from lst in myList where
         Convert.ToInt32(lst.A).CompareTo(-1) >= 0 &&
         Convert.ToInt32(lst.A).CompareTo(9999) <= 0 &&

         Convert.ToInt32(lst.B).CompareTo(-1) >= 0 &&
         Convert.ToInt32(lst.B).CompareTo(9999) <= 0 &&

         Convert.ToInt32(lst.C).CompareTo(-1) >= 0 &&
         Convert.ToInt32(lst.C).CompareTo(9999) <= 0
         select lst).ToList();
```

Comment: Yeah, sure. But what if one value is "ABAB" like this:
    myObj moB = new myObj("WithLetters", "3000", "ABAB", "5000");
?

Comment: I do not think even you understand what you want to do. You cannot really achieve both string and integer comparison can you? Very interesting down vote most likely because it is not clear to you what you want to achieve.